# Need help setting up Azure AD B2C SSO with Knack

Tags: azure, oauth, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Knack has an option to set up custom Single Sign On options. There are a few items I am unclear on as to where to find on Azure AD B2C. According to their [help article](https://support.knack.com/hc/en-us/articles/231796207-Single-Sign-On-with-Google-Facebook-and-Twitter#custom-sso-providers), I must provide the following information for OAuth 2.0:

- **Authorization URL:** the URL that your user is redirected to obtain permissions when they click the SSO button.
- **Access Token URL:** used to obtain a token to verify future requests to the authentication provider to act on your user’s behalf.
- **Profile URL (OAuth only) -** the URL where information about a user’s account can be retrieved. The Profile URL will be sent a GET request authenticated by the user’s token, and will be expected to return a JSON object.

For Authorization URL, I have tried to supply the 'Sign-up or Sign-in' Policy [endpoint](https://login.microsoftonline.com/zyxelcustomers.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_ZyxelCustomersSuSi&client_id=5123d588-f2a3-46da-9a7b-6e55e08ae8b4&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fzyxel.knack.com%2Fppos%2F&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login) as that takes you to the login page. I think this is right however I am unsure.

For Access Token URL,  I have tried either the Authorization Endpoint or Token Endpoint, but I'm not sure if those are right.

```
"authorization_endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/zyxelcustomers.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=b2c_1_zyxelcustomerssusi"

"token_endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/zyxelcustomers.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=b2c_1_zyxelcustomerssusi"
```

For Profile URL, I actually have no idea where I would find this on Azure AD B2C.

Single Sign On is new to me and I have gone through Azure AD documentation to try to help myself, but ultimately I am stuck.

Thanks in advance for your help and please let me know what other information I can provide.

Edit 9/26/2017: 
This B2C documentation describes the purpose of Authorization URL and Access Token URL.

In short, Authorization URL is the endpoint to send the user to enter their credentials. If credentials are valid, an authorization code will be returned via URL to the designated Reply URL. The client app will then use the returned authorization code to request for an access token from the Access Token URL. If successful, the client can now attach the access token as a Bearer token in the Authorization header to authorize future API calls before the token expires.

Unfortunately, as of this time of writing, AADB2C does not support calling the Azure AD Graph or Microsoft Graph API for user profile information.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to provide a Profile URL since Azure AD B2C uses Open ID Connect, and not OAuth (similar protocols, but not identical). The Profile URL field is optional, so try configuring it without filling out the field.